# How do I hide shipping and tax info from the cart page in Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My Woocommerce cart displays the shipping and tax information. I only want these info to appear once the customer provided their address (because tax rate and shipping cost would be calculated based on their address).

In admin I set the following:

- I checked "Hide shipping costs until an address is entered "
- I unchecked "Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page "
- In General settings "Default customer location" is set to no location by default

In tax settings I have the following settings:
[image]

i'm clueless why it still shows tax and shipping in cart, when it should only start calculating it once the customer provided their address.

Comment: Make sure you test this with a cleared cache and are not logged in.